# Search for text in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, comparative-review, console

I have this implementation of Grep where I use `re.search`:

```py
#!/bin/python

"""
A grep implementation on Python
"""

from re import search
from sys import argv


def grep(word, file):
    for line in file:
        if search(word, line):
            print(line.strip())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        grep(argv[1], open(argv[2]))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("That's not a vaild file.")
    except IndexError:
        print("Params missing!")
```

But if instead of using search I:

```py
def grep(word, file):
    for line in file:
        if word in line:
            print(line.strip())
```

Which is better or faster?
I think the more Pythonic way is the second one.

Comment: why would you reinvent grep? And if you want to reinvent grep, why would you avoid it's regular expression support?

Comment: You're correct, the second one is better [and it's also faster](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19911508/9997212).

Comment: @Vogel612 It's just a programming challenge, I've already passed the tests. I'd just like to know which one is better and why.

Comment: @enzo How is it better? It's not even trying to do the job it's supposed to do.

Comment: @KellyBundy It is not a true Grep implementation, it was just for a challenge that I found on a platform. I just wanted to know which method was more appropriate to take it into account in the future.

Comment: @EliazBobadilla Well, what's more appropriate depends on what you're doing. And it makes absolutely no sense to consider one of them more Pythonic than the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `re.escape(...)` in the first version, to match behaviour of the second.  Without it, special characters in `word` could be interpreted as regex patterns.

Catching `IndexError` only ensures the user has given enough arguments; it does not protect against too many.  `grep.py hello world file.txt` will search file `world` for the word `hello`, if it exists, instead of searching `file.txt` as expected.  Check the actual `argv` length, or better, use the `argparse` module.

Comment: I disagree with your first paragraph. The "re" in "grep" even stands for "regular expression". If you take that away, you don't have grep anymore.

Comment: @KellyBundy The first paragraph says, "_to match behaviour of the second._"  The programming challenge is clearly not about regular expressions, so the point of using `re.escape(...)` to match behaviour of the second implementation stands.  Your complaint is purely the code uses the name "grep" where it should be something else like "find_string", which is a valid point, but does not invalidate my point.

Comment: *"The programming challenge is clearly not about regular expressions"* - I don't think that's clear. And it's not just in the code, their text also says "implementation of Grep".

Answer (score 1):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep):

> grep is a command-line utility for searching plain-text data sets for lines that match a **regular expression**. Its name comes from the ed command g/re/p (**g**lobally search for a **r**egular **e**xpression and **p**rint matching lines)

So your second grep implementation really actually isn't one at all. Disqualified, case closed.